# How right way to round a very small negative number?

Tags: floating-point, rounding

There is a very very small negative number for example `-0.123e-35` which we get from previous computing.
The number may be used in some other formulas. Is it right way to round  this number suppose to ten decimal places to zero '0'? 
It's all right if this number will be used just in addition operation but it will give wrong result in multiplication operation. 
How right way to do it?

**UPD**

Why is it need to me? I realized DCT method on matrix. On test matrix 8x8 filled by '1'. I get this:

```
8 -7.49778027488703e-13 7.64321008887262e-13 -7.90698562193149e-13 8.26182651759402e-13 -8.78937758371177e-13 9.51152198392764e-13 -1.04158952401295e-12
-7.51721016906324e-13 1.66533453693773e-16 -2.77555756156289e-17 2.77555756156289e-17 2.77555756156289e-17 2.77555756156289e-17 -2.77555756156289e-17 1.38777878078145e-17
7.65773344411544e-13 2.77555756156289e-17 -1.38777878078145e-16 -2.77555756156289e-17 0 0 0 -1.38777878078145e-17
-7.91522860733958e-13 0 5.55111512312578e-17 -5.55111512312578e-17 -2.77555756156289e-17 -2.77555756156289e-17 -1.38777878078145e-17 -1.38777878078145e-17
8.26025642513534e-13 8.32667268468867e-17 -2.77555756156289e-17 0 0 5.55111512312578e-17 -6.93889390390723e-17 -6.93889390390723e-18
-8.78466730633572e-13 8.32667268468867e-17 -2.77555756156289e-17 -4.16333634234434e-17 1.11022302462516e-16 4.16333634234434e-17 -1.38777878078145e-17 5.55111512312578e-17
9.50946123757562e-13 -1.66533453693773e-16 -9.71445146547012e-17 2.77555756156289e-17 -9.71445146547012e-17 -1.38777878078145e-17 1.38777878078145e-17 -1.73472347597681e-17
-1.04131475783268e-12 -8.32667268468867e-17 4.16333634234434e-17 -4.16333634234434e-17 -1.38777878078145e-17 5.55111512312578e-17 2.77555756156289e-17 -4.16333634234434e-17
```

Also I do the same thing but in Scilab and it give me this:

> ```
> 8.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  
> 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  
> 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  
> 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  
> 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  
> 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  
> 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  
> 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
> ```

as you see there are just zeros. And I want to understand may I round those very small negative numbers to zero or not?

Comment: Why do you need to round the value?

Comment: You'd round to a specific number of significant digits, not to a particular number of places after the decimal point.

Comment: There are a lot of answers here that superficially solve the problem, but you have not specified your problem sufficiently clearly, so they may be useless.  So I ask again, what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: You should “correct” a tiny number to zero **only** if you know that it cannot be tiny unless the value computed exactly (with no arithmetic rounding errors) would be zero or if you can demonstrate mathematically that it improves your final result. This is why we are asking you to explain why you need to round. The right answer depends on the specific situation.

Comment: Regarding the new information that you've added to your question, are you sure this is not just how Scilab I'd choosing to **display** your values?

Comment: I've multiplied the result matrix by 2 and I got [16, 0, 0, ... etc]. So it's not just Scilab behavior to display numbers.

Comment: @edem: Multiplying by two is insufficient to demonstrate that Scilab is not merely rounding to a fixed format. Try multiplying by `1e20`.

Comment: `->b*1e20
 ans  =
  10^20 *
     8.    0.    0.    0. ...` got this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you have shown does not justify any need to round to zero. Most likely, you should simply disregard the fact that some of the results are tiny and continue with the work normally.

Perfect test data is not a good demonstration of a DCT. Real-world data rarely results in DCTs that have values that are exactly zero. Additionally, if you apply a DCT to real-world data and get a value that is small, it could be small because that is the mathematically correct result or because the mathematically correct result would be zero but there have been some errors. This means you would not have a way to determine whether a small value in the DCT results should be corrected to zero or left alone. So trying to change values to zero can actually make the data worse.

Furthermore, the small values are not likely to affect the work. Your application will use the results of the DCT to modify or analyze the signal and then will go on to perform an inverse transform or otherwise use the results. Generally, this further use will not be significantly affected by the presence of tiny errors in the data. (The errors from the microphone or other sensor or environmental noise are likely larger than these errors.)

In other words, these small values are only bothering you, the human, not the computer. Ignore them.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of answers here suggesting that you do something along the lines of `(x * 10^n) / 10^n`.  However, this does **not** round to `n` decimal places, in general.

Binary floating-point cannot exactly represent most finite decimal values, for example 0.1 would actually be 0.100000001490116...<sup>*</sup>  So if your aim is to obtain an exact representation of a finite decimal expansion (for subsequent calculations), this approach will not work; it will merely give you the **closest representable value** to what you were aiming for.  For exact representation, you would need to investigate a `BigDecimal` library/class (the details of which will vary from language to language).

However, if you only want to **display** values to 10 decimal places, then your language will probably offer something similar to C's `printf("%.10f\n", x);`.  This really will round to 10 decimal places for display purposes.

---

<sub>* See http://floating-point-gui.de/ for a beginner's introduction to this important issue.</sub>

Comment: I cannot quite vote for this answer—The OP indicates they are concerned that small numbers will product wrong results when multiplied. So their concern is not, as you write, “getting an exact representation of a finite decimal expansion”, but about trying to “correct” an intermediate value. It seems they have some belief that a value near zero is only non-zero because of arithmetic errors. That might be appropriate or inappropriate, depending on circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

To round to 10 decimal places in JavaScript (as the question was originally tagged), simply do the following.

```
var num = 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000123; // 1.23e-35
num = Math.round(num * 10000000000) / 10000000000;  // 0

var num = 0.000000000123; // 1.23e-10
num = Math.round(num * 10000000000) / 10000000000;  // 1e-10
```

Please note that while the above will yield the results you're looking for, floating point values are not true decimal values, and attempting to "round" them may have unexpected results in some cases.  However, this solution will ensure that any number less than 0.00000000005 will be rounded to 0, which I think is what you are looking for.

Possibly a better solution for your problem than rounding all numbers would be conditionally set the value to 0 if it's < 0.00000000005

```
if (num < 0.00000000005) num = 0;
```

Comment: Binary floating-point doesn't really have the concept of decimal places, so this doesn't work in general.

Comment: Any reason for the negative?  This is absolutely the correct solution to the given question.

Comment: I downvoted because this gives the misleading impression that decimal places make sense in floating-point.

Comment: Math.round returns a long, so you have to divide by a floating point value.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - No, it doesn't.  Floating point values still abide by the rules of math.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - No, you don't.  int / int can yield a float

Comment: @StevenMoseley Only if cast to a float, but that float will not have any fractional part.

Comment: @StevenMoseley: No.  Most finite decimal expansions cannot be exactly represented in binary floating-point ([here's an example in C](http://ideone.com/0tPyGo)).  So the notion of reliably rounding to a finite number of decimal places is misleading, at best.  We need to understand what the OP is trying to achieve first.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Never the less it works despite your protestations.

Comment: @StevenMoseley Not so mysterious given the Double.toString is designed to print the simplest number which has the representation. i.e. it hides the fact that 0.1 is not really 0.1

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Steven: Sure, in this particular case where the aim is to obtain zero.  It doesn't work reliably in general (depending on your definition of "reliably", of course...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - There's no alternative given the JS toolbox.  So would you argue that one should simply give up, or use a solution that's known to work?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This is true.  You have to round to a expected level of precision after any calculations and not try to print more digits of precision than the floating point has.  BTW never use `float` unless you really, really have to.

Comment: @StevenMoseley: That's why I've asked the OP what (s)he's trying to achieve.  If the aim is to have a value that's a precise 10-d.p. value, then the answer is "that's not possible in general".  If the question is, for example, "how do I **display** to 10 d.p.?", then that's a solvable problem.  As is "how do I round to the closest representable value to a 10-d.p. value?".

Comment: @StevenMoseley You can use BigDecimal but it's 100+x slower and more complicated which is waste given you can get the same result with `double` for most practical situations.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - The OP was pretty clear, I thought.  He wanted values between -0.0000000001 and 0 to equate to 0, but anything < -0.0000000001 to be "rounded" to 10 dp

Comment: @StevenMoseley: I agree, depending on what the OP requires in "rounding", your answer may well be correct.  (But I still feel you should add clarification, as the realities of floating-point may leave the OP sorely disappointed!).

Comment: FYI: regarding the tags, the OP originally tag-spammed this with every language under the sun.  So I removed them all, pending further clarification... ;)

Comment: Added explanation and more info

Comment: I've updated the question and added the reason for my question.

Answer (score 0):

In python this is

```
round(n*(1e10))/(1e10)
```

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, where does it say that? Some answers are in java.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to round to N decimal places is to use round, note this returns a `long` so you must divide by a double value or you can get integer division.

```
double rounded = Math.round(d * 1e10) / 1e10;
```

Using 1eN notation makes it clearer how may digits you want to round to.  To ensure you don't overflow you need a bounds check.

```
public static double round10(double d) {
    final double factor = 1e10;
    return d > Long.MAX_VALUE / factor || d < -Long.MAX_VALUE / factor ?
            (long) (d < 0 ? d * factor - 0.5 : d * factor + 0.5) / factor : d;
}
```

Here I have used casting instead of rounding as it is almost as accurate but much faster.